# How do I decrease the minimum font size in Sublime Text 3

Tags: fonts, sublime-text-3, accessibility, sublime-text

If I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> key combinations I can lower my font size down to 8pt, even though if I edit my user preferences I can set this to whatever I like. Problem is once I do that, any use of the above key combinations resets the font to at least 8pt.

Is there are way to override this behaviour/lower the minimum font size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this link](http://funkdancer.com/2012/10/03/decrease-minimum-font-size-in-sublime-editor/), you will need to edit a core file in Sublime Text. I tried it and had to tweak the procedure to make it work with ST3.

I found the easiest way is to use [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) to open up the `Default` package in Sublime Text and edit the `font.py` file:

1. In Sublime, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the Command Palette and select `PackageResourceViewer > Open Resource`, select `Default`, then `font.py`.
2. In the opened file, edit lines 34 and 35 and set your own custom minimum:

   ```
   if current < 8:
       current = 8
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. If it doesn't work straight away, restart Sublime.

This will not actually edit any core files, but a new `Packages/Default/font.py` file in your user data folder will shadow the one from core Sublime, making this a pretty non-invasive procedure.